# How to annotate a program to detect dead-code with z3-solver?

Tags: code-coverage, z3, z3py, dead-code, symbolic-execution

**Intro**

Given a simple function written in C++ as below:

```
int func(int x, int y)
{
    if (x < 3)
    {
        y = 4;
        if (x < 4)
        {
            y = y + 2;
        }
        else
        {
            x = x + 4;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        x = x + 1;
    }

    return x + y;
};
```

**Problem**

How to annotate the program to do the followings in `z3`?

1. Detect Dead Codes. (x = x + 4)
2. Generate test cases (Code coverage).
3. Analyze invariants.
4. `Pre` & `Post` code checks.

**What I did?**

I know that I need to identify each path for every block in the code:

```
PATH 1 for (y = 4) => (x < 3)
PATH 2 for (y = y + 2) => (x < 3) ^ (x < 4)
PATH 3 for (x = x + 4) => (x < 3) ^ (x >= 4)
PATH 4 for (x = x + 1) => (x >= 3)
```

Then if I use Z3 I can check if any of these paths are `unsat` which infers that the code block related to them will be `Dead code`.

**What help I need?**

- For the dead code detection:

I really don't know how to show the above in `z3`. Should I use different solvers for each path? like this:

```
from z3 import *

x = Int('x')
y = Int('y)
s1 = Solver()
s2 = Solver()
s3 = Solver()
s4 = Solver()

s1.add(x < 3)
s2.add(x < 3, x < 4)
s3.add(x < 3, x >= 4)
s4.add(x >= 3)

s1.check() // sat
s2.check() // sat
s3.check() // unsat
s4.check() // sat
```

I think this is an inefficient way of detecting dead codes. What if there have been a hundred different paths? So there must be a better way to do this.

- For Analyzing invariants:

Again, should I use different solvers for each code block? For example:

```
from z3 import *

s1 = Solver()
s2 = Solver()
s3 = Solver()
s4 = Solver()
x0 = Int('x0')
y0 = Int('y0)
x1 = Int('x1')
y1 = Int('y1')

// Path 1
s1.add(x0 < 3)
s1.add(y0 == 4)
s1.add(y1 == y0 + 2)
s1.check()
s1.model()

// Path 2
s2.add(x0 < 3)
s2.add(y0 == 4)
s2.add(x1 == x0 + 4);
s2.check()
s2.model()

// Path 3
s3.add(x0 < 3)
s3.add(y0 == 4)
s3.add(x1 == x0 + 4);
s3.check()
s3.model()

// Path 4
s3.add(x0 >= 3)
s3.add(x1 == x0 + 1);
s3.check()
s3.model()
```

- And I have no idea how to `Generate test cases` and do `Pre` & `Post` code checks

Finally, My question actually is, how to analyze a program with z3 for different scenarios such as `Dead Code Detection`, `Invariant analysis`, `Test-case generation`, etc. To be more specific, I am looking for the best-practices in this regard. A sample code in `z3-solver` will help a lot. More preferably, I would like to see how to improve the sample `z3` codes that I provided above.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stack-overflow works the best if you focus on just one question. All of these are doable using z3, but the important question to ask is if you are interested in just this one given program, or are you interested in building something that works for arbitrary C programs?

If your interest is in the latter, then this is a much more difficult task to tackle, and you should really be looking at symbolic-execution/analysis papers. If you're interested in just this program, then you should follow-up with a path analysis: For dead-code, you want to know if there's any code path that is not reachable, i.e., if a particular if-statement never takes its `then` or `else` branch. Note that you should use only one solver, not a different one for each path. You can use the solver incrementally, as you do a depth-first search of the control flow.

The techniques you're after are usually considered as part of the DART research, which also covers test-case generation. Start by reading this paper: [https://web.eecs.umich.edu/~weimerw/2014-6610/reading/p213-godefroid.pdf](https://web.eecs.umich.edu/%7Eweimerw/2014-6610/reading/p213-godefroid.pdf)

Again, stack-overflow works the best if you ask very specific and a very focused question on one particular aspect. Once you review the above paper, I'm sure you'll have better questions!

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I am now reading the paper and I found it very interesting so far. You are also correct about my OP being too general to be answered in SO. I realized that after I posted it. However I am not deleting this because your answer might help others too. Thanks again.